# What happened to my Inactive Widgets?

Tags: themes, widgets

I have purchased the DynamiX theme, and I'm trying to use it for the first time.

I was looking at the widgets, and I saw some neat customized (Dynamic maybe?) widgets in the Inactive Widgets section. I was going to drag one to my Sidebar, but accidentally dropped it, and now it is gone. Is there any way to retrieve those? I don't even know exactly what it was, I just know that it was part of my theme.

I'm pretty new to Wordpress, so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inactive widgets are just normal widgets from the "Available widgets" list, which have been put in the "Inactive" section in order to keep the data they contained.

What probably happened is that you dropped one of them over the "Available widgets" space and it dissapeared. But don't worry that doesn't mean that the widget is gone, widgets cannot "dissapear", in the worst case you just lost the data of the widget.

For example if you have a text widget in your colum, with the title "My cool widget" and the text "Hey check this out", and you decide to temporarly remove it from your website, but wish to keep the text data, you would drop it to the "Inactive" space. You can then drop it back whenever you wish to use it again with the same text. BUT, if you remove it completely, then there will always still be the "Text" widget available in the upper space "Available widgets".

Hope that helps.

Comment: It definitely gave me a better understanding.

I think my theme came with some preset inactive widgets, and I'm not sure what they were I guess. I'll have to do some research.